# Using environment variables in POST payload

Tags: postman

Can I use environment variables set in a previous test in the payload I am posting?

eg.

```
POST /list

{
    "some_key": environment.saved_value
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. You send it up like this

```
{ 
    "some_key" : "{{environment_variable_name}}"
}
```

So, if in your previous test you had set it with something like

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("id","some_value")
```

You can use it in your POST with

```
{ 
"some_key" : "{{id}}" 
}
```

Hopefully, that answers your question

Comment: this does not seem to work with boolean values, I tried `{ "val" : "{{myval}}" }` where `myval` in the environmnent is true yet when the put hits the server it comes through as false

Comment: also this does not work when submitting a request through newman

Comment: it seems it does not work with string types through newman, but numeric types are fine